# How to check where did memory goes when oom-killer invoked in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, out-of-memory, linux-device-driver

In our system, oom-killer is invoked when we have large throughput, we believe that most of the memory should be consumed by kernel driver, but we can't find the dedicated consumer, really appreciate anyone can give some suggestion for it.

followed is the detailed log of dmesg

```
[14839.077171] passkey-agent invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201da, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[14839.077187] CPU: 0 PID: 3443 Comm: passkey-agent Tainted: G           O    4.1.35-rt41 #1
[14839.077190] Hardware name: LS1043A RDB Board (DT)
[14839.077193] Call trace:
[14839.079644] [<ffff8000000898f4>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x154
[14839.079650] [<ffff800000089a5c>] show_stack+0x14/0x1c
[14839.079656] [<ffff8000008f3174>] dump_stack+0x90/0xb0
[14839.079663] [<ffff80000013eea4>] dump_header.isra.10+0x88/0x1b8
[14839.079668] [<ffff80000013f5f8>] oom_kill_process+0x210/0x3d4
[14839.079672] [<ffff80000013faec>] __out_of_memory.isra.15+0x330/0x374
[14839.079676] [<ffff80000013fd5c>] out_of_memory+0x5c/0x80
[14839.079682] [<ffff8000001442d8>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x55c/0x7c4
[14839.079687] [<ffff80000013e0cc>] filemap_fault+0x188/0x400
[14839.079693] [<ffff80000015f424>] __do_fault+0x3c/0x98
[14839.079698] [<ffff8000001641c8>] handle_mm_fault+0xc28/0x14f8
[14839.079704] [<ffff800000094c04>] do_page_fault+0x224/0x2b4
[14839.079709] [<ffff8000000822a0>] do_mem_abort+0x40/0xa0
[14839.079713] Exception stack(0xffff80001e47be20 to 0xffff80001e47bf50)
[14839.079719] be20: 00000000 00000000 000001f4 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff a6f90990 0000ffff
[14839.079725] be40: ffffffff ffffffff 3b969772 00000000 dbbcc280 0000ffff 00085db0 ffff8000
[14839.079730] be60: 00000000 00000000 000001f4 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff a6f90990 0000ffff
[14839.079736] be80: 1e47bea0 ffff8000 000895f8 ffff8000 00000008 00000000 00085b90 ffff8000
[14839.079742] bea0: dbbcc280 0000ffff 00085c9c ffff8000 00000000 00000000 0ee34088 00000000
[14839.079747] bec0: 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 dbbcc2b0 0000ffff 00000000 00000000
[14839.079752] bee0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 000f4240 00000000 00000000 00000000
[14839.079758] bf00: 00000049 00000000 0000001c 00000000 0000011b 00000000 00000013 00000000
[14839.079763] bf20: 00000028 00000000 00000000 00000000 a71c1c20 0000ffff 00000000 003b9aca
[14839.079767] bf40: a720a990 0000ffff a6f90918 0000ffff
[14839.082683] Mem-Info:
[14839.082700] active_anon:16910 inactive_anon:6202 isolated_anon:0
                active_file:15 inactive_file:0 isolated_file:26
                unevictable:62887 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
                slab_reclaimable:944 slab_unreclaimable:8027
                mapped:5421 shmem:2349 pagetables:527 bounce:0
                free:5120 free_pcp:627 free_cma:0
[14839.082719] DMA free:20480kB min:22528kB low:28160kB high:33792kB active_anon:67640kB inactive_anon:24808kB active_file:60kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:251548kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):104kB present:1046528kB managed:890652kB mlocked:251548kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:21684kB shmem:9396kB slab_reclaimable:3776kB slab_unreclaimable:32108kB kernel_stack:6064kB pagetables:2108kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:2508kB local_pcp:424kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:208 all_unreclaimable? no
[14839.082723] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
[14839.082729] DMA: 755*4kB (EM) 486*8kB (UEM) 617*16kB (UEM) 2*32kB (M) 1*64kB (R) 2*128kB (R) 1*256kB (R) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (R) 1*2048kB (R) 0*4096kB = 20492kB
[14839.082752] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
[14839.082755] 7756 total pagecache pages
[14839.082760] 0 pages in swap cache
[14839.082763] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[14839.082765] Free swap  = 0kB
[14839.082768] Total swap = 0kB
[14839.082856] 261632 pages RAM
[14839.082858] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
[14839.082861] 34873 pages reserved
[14839.082863] 4096 pages cma reserved
[14839.082867] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
[14839.082890] [ 1353]     0  1353      876      161       7       3        0         -1000 udevd
[14839.082899] [ 1863]   999  1863      695       48       5       3        0             0 dbus-daemon
[14839.082906] [ 1944]     0  1944      833       23       5       3        0             0 syslogd
[14839.082913] [ 1947]     0  1947      833       18       5       3        0             0 klogd
[14839.082919] [ 1990]     0  1990     2307      686       8       2        0             0 php-fpm
[14839.082925] [ 1991] 65534  1991     2307      857       8       2        0             0 php-fpm
[14839.082932] [ 1992] 65534  1992     2307      857       8       2        0             0 php-fpm
[14839.082938] [ 1999]     0  1999      720       31       5       3        0             0 bash
[14839.083042] [ 2001]     0  2001     1083      393       6       3        0             0 start_appli
[14839.083049] [ 2010]     0  2010      849       26       5       3        0             0 getty
[14839.083055] [ 2115]     0  2115     1262       96       6       4        0         -1000 sshd
[14839.083062] [ 3051]     0  3051     2709      210       6       2        0             0 optf_write
[14839.083068] [ 3052]     0  3052     1719      686       7       2        0             0 launcher
[14839.083074] [ 3055]     0  3055     5056     4196      13       2        0             0 globMW0
[14839.083081] [ 3066]     0  3066    10430     6805      27       2        0             0 confd
[14839.083088] [ 3085]     0  3085     9735     7449      23       2        0             0 hal0
[14839.083095] [ 3086]     0  3086     7781     6642      19       2        0             0 SystemMgr
[14839.083102] [ 3087]     0  3087     7455     6372      20       2        0             0 HWMgr
[14839.083108] [ 3088]     0  3088     8319     7118      20       2        0             0 SWMgr
[14839.083115] [ 3089]     0  3089     7824     6696      19       2        0             0 FaultMgr
[14839.083121] [ 3090]     0  3090     7488     6359      20       2        0             0 TSMgr
[14839.083127] [ 3091]     0  3091     7009     6144      20       2        0             0 SecurityMgr
[14839.083133] [ 3092]     0  3092     7736     6337      20       2        0             0 DHCPRelayMgr
[14839.083225] [ 3093]     0  3093     8747     6555      21       2        0             0 ItfMgr
[14839.083232] [ 3094]     0  3094     8192     6686      21       2        0             0 WlanItfMgr
[14839.083239] [ 3095]     0  3095     7602     6518      20       2        0             0 L2Mgr
[14839.083246] [ 3096]     0  3096     7399     6017      20       2        0             0 QoSMgr
[14839.083252] [ 3097]     0  3097     8647     6486      21       2        0             0 L3Mgr
[14839.083258] [ 3098]     0  3098     7482     6356      17       2        0             0 MulticastMgr
[14839.083264] [ 3099]     0  3099     7783     6609      21       2        0             0 DHCPMgr
[14839.083271] [ 3100]     0  3100     6864     6409      16       2        0             0 CallHomeMgr
[14839.083279] [ 3422]     0  3422      472       23       4       3        0             0 hciattach
[14839.083286] [ 3426]     0  3426     1035       50       6       3        0             0 bluetoothd
[14839.083292] [ 3443]     0  3443     2039      112       8       3        0             0 passkey-agent
[14839.083298] [ 3462]     0  3462     3852     2368      11       3        0             0 dhcpd
[14839.083304] [ 3517]     0  3517      860      161       7       3        0         -1000 udevd
[14839.083393] [ 3518]     0  3518      860      161       7       3        0         -1000 udevd
[14839.083400] [ 3650]     0  3650     1629      132       6       3        0             0 wpa_supplicant
[14839.083406] [ 3720]     0  3720     3134     1711      10       3        0             0 dhclient
[14839.083412] [ 3747]     0  3747      891      149       6       3        0             0 zebra
[14839.083419] [ 3751]     0  3751      834      132       7       3        0             0 ripd
[14839.083425] [ 3949]     0  3949     1037       67       6       4        0             0 ntpd
[14839.083431] [ 8000]     0  8000      721       33       5       3        0             0 sh
[14839.083436] Out of memory: Kill process 3085 (hal0) score 32 or sacrifice child
[14839.083447] Killed process 3085 (hal0) total-vm:38940kB, anon-rss:15236kB, file-rss:14560kB
```

We have 1G memory in total, and I can found that slab occupied about 35M (3776kB + 32108kB), the kernel stuck is 6064kB, and active_anon + inactive_anon is about 92M (67640kB + 24808kB), and the user space memory consumption is normal as usual.

So where did the memory left goes ? How can I check with it ?
For example, how can I check how much memory it consumed by a dedicated driver of pcie network card?

Comment: If your kernel is configured to use SLUB (which is kind of the default these days), you can try enabling `CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG` and `CONFIG_SLUB_STATS` in your kernel and investigate the data available from there (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/slub.txt).

Comment: Thanks @oakad, it seems that our platform is not using SLUB.
CONFIG_SLAB=y
# CONFIG_SLUB is not set

Comment: 1. Switching to a newer SLUB or SLOB (which is more small memory friendly) may fix your issues outright. 2. `/proc/slabinfo` should be available even with SLAB (+/- some additional kernel options).